# Passing data to a click listener

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, jquery-events

I have a button in my html that when clicked,  I need it to pass the index attribute value to my click listener:

```
<button class="btn buy-button js-prevent-cart-listener guys" index="1">Add To Cart</button>
```

and the listener:

```
$('.girls').on('click', buyButtonGirlsClickHandler, index);
```

So that when I  run this function, I can access the event value and use it within the function:

```
function buyButtonClickHandler(evt) {
    console.log(evt.value);
  }
```

I dont want to change it to have an 'onclick()' attached to the button. Is this possible and if so how? Obviously the code  above is  not able to  pass the index value, and i have tried numerous times

Comment: `var index = this.getAttribute("index")`

Answer (score 1):

You need not to pass the index in on function. You should try changing your on function to

```
$('.girls').on('click', buyButtonGirlsClickHandler);
```

and in the handler you can receive it by `attr`

```
function buyButtonClickHandler(evt) {
    console.log(evt.value);
    var index=  $(event.target).attr("index");
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/525npjfn/

or as @Andreas commented , use this inside click.

```
function buyButtonGirlsClickHandler(evt) {
    console.log(evt.value);
        var index = this.getAttribute("index");
        alert(index);
  }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/525npjfn/2/

Answer (score 0):

On button click, you can store it's index value in a variable and then pass it into the desired function. This is the clean snippet to solve your problem.

Please use `data-` prefix to use custom HTML attribute otherwise HTML validators will cry for this.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.js-prevent-cart-listener').click(function() {
    var idx = $(this).attr('data-index');
    buyButtonClickHandler(idx);
  })
});

function buyButtonClickHandler(idx) {
  console.log("This is index value " + idx);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn buy-button js-prevent-cart-listener guys" data-index="1">Add To Cart</button>
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of passing the event handler directly, wrap it inside a new function. Your index data will be passed because it stays in the scope.

```
let index = "whatever your index data is";
$('.girls').on('click', (e, index) => buyButtonGirlsClickHandler(e, index) );
```

Note: I'm using ES6 syntax there, may not work on old browsers.

Comment: The index is an attribute of the clicked button